# C# Async methods never being called

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, asynchronous, xamarin.forms

I am writing a program that stores a JSON file of quiz questions on an Azure database, as well as on an SQLite local database (offline sync in case you have no internet). I am using Async methods in my code and my `Console.WriteLine()` are not firing in them.

I am new to Asynchronous function calls and am following a Xamarin University tutorial found here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsKjJ6ohjSA

```
protected async override void OnStart()
    {
        var fileHelper = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>();
        var azureService = new AzureService();
        var questions = await azureService.GetQuestions(); //isn't being called
        //more stuff...
    }
```

The above function calls the function below

```
public async Task<List<QuizQuestion>> GetQuestions()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is not being called");
        await Initialize();
        await SyncQuestions();
        return await table.ToListAsync();
    }
```

this function also calls an `await Initialize();`

```
public async Task Initialize()
    {
        //lots of code ...

        Console.WriteLine("Path is: " + path); //never output in Console

        //more code is here...
    }
```

It seems as though my local database isnt pushing my questions to the Azure cloud database, and I'm worried that the functions are not being called at all as my `Console.Writeline()` functions aren't displaying in my log. Is this correct?

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint at OnStart first line of code and going step by step?

Comment: Step by step the lines are Console.WriteLine calls are displayed

Comment: Did you allready put a WriteLine in the beginning of OnStart, to verify, that you see the output. Just in case

Comment: I get the output yes @RomanoZumbé

Comment: I have checked the tutorial and from your code snippet, I do not see any issue. Per my understanding, you could follow this official [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started#download-and-run-the-xamarinforms-solution) to create your azure mobile app backend, then download and run the Xamarin.Forms sample solution that has supports offline sync. Also, you could refer to Adrian hall's book about [Data access and Offline Sync](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/dataconcepts/).